# Creating a clickable progress bar

Tags: javascript, webkit, controller, progress-bar, clickable

What I'm essentially building is a webkit based controller that communicates with a program called Ecoute.app.

The controller has a progressbar that indicates the progress made through the currently playing song, but I want to make this bar's position adjustable with a click.

```
function barClick() { 
    var progress = Ecoute.playerPosition(); 
    var width = 142.5;

    var percentElapsed = progress / length;
    var position = width * percentElapsed;

    Ecoute.setPlayerPosition(position);  
}
```

Is what I have, with `Ecoute.playerPosition()` returning the player's current position.

Width has previously been defined as a dynamic value at

```
 var width = 142.5 / length * progress + 1.63;
```

With length being the current track length and progress being the player's position. This has been able to dynamically stretch a progression overlay image to indicate the position of the track via the desktop controller.

However, the max width used in the second function does not appear to allow the first function to work properly.

Any help possibly determining the correct value or approach would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to really know where you are getting stuck. My guess is you are having problems getting the click to work and determining where to set the progress.

My solution is to have 2 elements, one wrapping the other. The outer element takes the click event and the size gets reflected by the inner element. You will have to do your own work integrating with the Ecoute player but I showed how to calculate the percentage.

```
var outside = document.getElementById('outside');
var inside = document.getElementById('inside');

outside.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  inside.style.width = e.offsetX + "px";

  // calculate the %
  var pct = Math.floor((e.offsetX / outside.offsetWidth) * 100);
  inside.innerHTML = pct + " %";
}, false);
```

*I didn't bother with any cross browser work since this is for a webkit based application.*

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ubana3/5

Comment: Is there any way to quantify the output from the above in to an integer? IE, simply have the percentage output be, say, a decimal value that I could then multiply by the current track length to determine track positioning?

Comment: Basically I need to do something along the lines of function barClick () { var pct = ? var length = track.property('length'); var result = length * pct Ecoute.setPlayerPosition(result);} Where pct = ? I tried plugging in math.floor((e.offsetX / outside.offsetwidth) * 100); to no avail, even after changing the appropriate IDs.

Comment: @Cory You have an inside and outside div? You get the event to fire and you can alert the calculated pct value? The pct that I calculated is an integer. Try dividing it by 100 before you multiply it with length or explaining what *to no avail* means.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML,

0% played< /progress>

In JQuery,

```
mediaPlayer = document.getElementById(playerId);
progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');

progressBar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     var percentage = Math.floor((e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth) * 100);
     mediaPlayer.currentTime  = mediaPlayer.duration*(percentage/100);
     progressBar.value        = percentage;
     progressBar.innerHTML    = percentage + '% played';          
});
```